# Как проще всего сделать одинаковые сайт и мобильное приложение, используя React?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Стоит задача написать веб-приложение на React c ssr, а потом как-то максимально безболезненно сделать из него мобильное приложение.

Мобильные приложения раньше не делал, сейчас пытаюсь разобраться. Как я понимаю, лучший вариант для меня – React Native.

Что веб-версия, что мобильная будут выглядеть примерно одинаково и иметь одинаковую бизнес логику, так что хочется иметь максимально общую кодовую базу.

В React Native не поддерживается css, но можно использовать styled components.
Правильно я понимаю, что используя styled components, я смогу создавать универсальные компоненты, которые будут поддерживаться и там и там?

Можете посоветовать какие-нибудь ui-библиотеки, которые будут работать и в React и в React Native? Правильно я понимаю, что мне подойдут Evergreen/Grommet/Rebase?

Что ещё следует учесть заранее, чтобы было меньше боли при переносе на React Native?

Может я вообще думаю не в эту сторону и нужно делать всё по другому. В общем как бы вы делали проект на реакте, зная что потом нужно будет аналогичное мобильное приложение?

Answer (score 0):

В плане библиотек можете посмотреть на AntDesign или какие-то аналогичные. Это в принципе не так важно, самое главное чтобы поддержка была на обеих фреймворках и компоненты были одинаковые. Все равно сделать прям одинаковый код я думаю не получится.

Но если у вас одинаковая логика и в принципе дизайн не отличается, то я бы просто на вашем месте оптимизировал мобильную версию на сайте, а после этого загружал бы ее через [WebView](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview) в мобильном приложении на React Native. Так например делает Steam и некоторые другие проекты.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Да, наверное на antdesign и остановлюсь. Про webview думал, но как-то не очень нравится такое решение. Начну пока делать веб-версию, посмотрим как получится её перенести на RN..

Comment: В принципе вся логика, запросы, стейт-менеджмент у вас будут похожими на обоих платформах. По дизайну будут небольшие различия в плане компонентов и их использовании, но думаю это не страшно и решается просто использованием крупных библиотек, поддерживающих обе платформы. Единственное самое крупное различие которое я вижу, это в навигации, но думаю разобраться в ней можно за несколько дней. Остаются только локальные проблемы, статусбары, размеры и прочее. 
Что касается стилей, то я бы не мешал css с rn-styles. Поэтому для переноса использовал бы конвертер. 
Желаю удачи!)

Comment: Спасибо большое!